# Best way to marshal map to struct fields in GO

Tags: go

I want to know which is the best way to create instances of a certain struct based on a `map[string]string`

My app should process huge files in CSV format and should create an instance of a struct for each row of the file.

I'm already using the `encoding/csv/Reader` from golang to read the CSV file and create an instance of `map[string]string` for each row in the file.

So given this file:

```
columnA, columnB, columnC
a, b, c
```

My own reader implementation will return this map (each row values with the header):

```
myMap := map[string]string{
  "columnA": "a",
  "columnB": "b",
  "columnC": "c",
}
```

(this is just an example in real life the file contains a lot of columns and rows)

so.. at this point I need to create an instance of the struct that is related with the row contents, let say:

```
type MyStruct struct {
   AColumn string
   BColumn string
   CColumn string
}
```

My question is what could be the best way to create the instance of the struct using the given map, I have already implemented a version that just copy each value from the map to the struct but the code ended up being very long and tedious:

```
s := &MyStruct{}
s.AColumn := m["columnA"] 
s.AColumn := m["columnB"] 
s.AColumn := m["columnC"] 
...
```

I also consider using this library https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure but I don't know if using reflection could be the best approach considering that the file is huge and will be using reflection for each row.

Maybe there is no other option but I'm asking just in case someone knows a better approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show a [mcve]. Also, that's not a map. The csv Reader will normally return a `[]string` or `[][]string`.

Comment: You are right, the CVSReader returns an array []string but my code attach the header of the CSV to each row along with the values, I mean, I have implemented a wrapper using the CSVReader that return each row with the values and the header on each iteration, I think I made myself clear and there is no need to show an MRE

Comment: Then you have the option of using the JSON marshal/unmarshal to convert from map->[]byte->struct.

Comment: Yes I also thought about that option but the marshal/unmarshall use reflection and I don't want to affect the performance, I'm going to run some tests to see if it's worth it

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the *idiomatic Go way* would be just populating the struct's fields from your map. Go favors explicitness this approach is the more direct and the easiest to read. In other words, your approach is correct.

You could make it slightly nicer by initializing the struct directly:

```
s := &MyStruct{
  AColumn: m["columnA"],
  BColumn: m["columnB"],
  CColumn: m["columnC"],
}
```

Now, if your structure has 100s of fields (which is an odd design choice), you may want to [leverage some code generation](https://blog.golang.org/generate). Otherwise, just go with the straightforward code - it's the best approach in the long term.

Comment: And what about reflection.. how much the performance will be affected if I use that lib

Comment: @AndrewSullivan: it's difficult to say without profiling your specific application. It could be a major difference, or it may be completely negligible. Performance is only one aspect you should consider when choosing alternatives, and it should be very carefully measured in the context of your application (not as a generalized statement such as "reflection is expensive"). As an example, the Go `encoding/json` package uses reflection for precisely this purpose - mapping serialized data (in JSON) to Go structs.

Answer (score 0):

I already posted a library that I made for some stuff I have needed sometimes, I've made a MapToStruct fews months ago, I pushed that today to share with you the full library. The library is based in the usage of reflect, I still testing and implementing stuff, you will find some odd comments and these kind of things.

https://github.com/FedeMFernandez/goscript

I Hope it is useful

Comment: Thanks Fede! Nice work!, I will look into it, I also mentioned another option to do the same thing using reflection, here it is: https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure

Comment: I didn't see that link (sry), thanks for sharing it again I will read the code to understand more things about reflection and mapping. The name of goscript it's because I ment to create some js based go functions.